# Persistant Banner for Ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, python, security, debian, rpm

In my exploration of Ubuntu, and learning Linux systems as a whole, I came across this GitHub that creates a persistent banner for whats looks to be just RPM based Linux systems. I do not know much about the difference between Debian and RPM based Linux distributions, or in this case how python may or may not bridge the gap.

So I guess my question would be would something written for RPM systems with python be compatible with Ubuntu 16.04? I need something similar to this function for my Ubuntu systems.

Link in question: https://github.com/fcaviggia/classification-banner

Comment: Somebody moderately experienced with Python could probably get it to work fairly quickly. Note that this script is *specifically intended* for RHEL6, so you are likely to need to edit the script a bit. Since it's a rather simple script, the packaging does not seem relevant - simply install the script as a Python script instead of as a software package.

Comment: I don't think this is exclusively for RTM based systems. In fact, the python setup procedure apparently bypasses the whole package management system. Moreover it has been tested on Gnome 2 and 3 so it will run on Ubuntu 16.04 with Gnome. It may, however, not run on 16.04 with Unity.

Comment: I have always been unsure about Gnome and Unity. I wanna say 16.04 has both but defaults to Unity, correct? If that's the case then the systems we use run Unity. That being said, I took a python class in early highschool and remember next to nothing about the language at this point. So seeing it tested for Gnome, I was hopeful but then though Unity was the default.

Comment: I seem to remember Unity was the default on 16.04 and Gnome used to look a lot different. You may not want your users to get used to a different desktop environment.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of, thank you. I can't find a way to do something similar in Unity and don't have enough knowledge yet to attempt doing it myself, considering I am not even sure what I would need to be editing or adding to.

Answer (score 0):

[fcaviggia/classification-banner](https://github.com/fcaviggia/classification-banner), or its fork [SecurityCentral/classification-banner](https://github.com/SecurityCentral/classification-banner/) that's been [packaged for EPEL](https://src.fedoraproject.org/rpms/classification-banner), work fine on Ubuntu. It is a Python application that is not made specifically for Fedora-based distributions. You can easily create a Debian package of `classification-banner` using [stdeb](https://pypi.org/project/stdeb/).